# Which table stores the information about constraints in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I am new to databases. I want to know which table stores all the constraint info for SQL Server, like the `USER_CONSTRAINTS` & `USER_CONS_COLUMNS` views in Oracle.

How can I find the constraints for SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look first at the information schema views:

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS

is probably the one you want but there are a couple of others that might hellp you get information you want.

Answer (score 1):

Phil Factor recently wrote up a lot of examples:[Exploring foreign key relationships with system views](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/philfactor/archive/2010/09/23/94654.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> In **SQL Server** the **data dictionary** is a set of database tables used to
> store information about a database’s definition. One can use these
> data dictionaries to check the constraints on an already existing
> table and to change them(if possible).
>
> **USER_CONSTRAINTS Data Dictionary**: This data dictionary contains
> information about each constraint used in a database along with
> constraint specific information.